# How to look at Constructors in OOP

Tags: oop, class, constructor

In most OOP books and articles, we read something like this about constructors:

> A constructor is a specialized method in a class, its name is identical
>   to the class name, and it has no return type.

So our constructor is of this form:

```
class MyClass {
    public: /* no return type */ MyClass();
}
```

Well, this definition has some conflicts with OOP principles: methods must have an return type (even if `void`), and in an object, we cannot have 2 members with the same name, so a method cannot has the same name as the class's name.

I think we can change the definition to something like this one:

> A constructor is a specialized method in a class, it has no name – an
>   anonymous or nameless method – and its return type is
>   (the type of) the class.

So we will have:

```
class MyClass {
    public: MyClass /* no method name */ ();
}
```

In the second definition: we are allowed to have anonymous methods in most OOP languages, and our method has a really return type.

```
var obj = new MyClass();
```

Constructor called, and `obj` is an instance of `MyClass`, so constructor has a return value. In the other hand, `new MyClass()` is a contract for calling an accessible anonymous method on a blueprint of an object named `MyClass`.

What do you think? Am I wrong or can we use this definition or take this perspective to looking at constructors?

**UPDATE:**
Why am I getting down and close votes? Explain please.

Comment: As you have mentioned, a constructor is a `specialized` function. `Specialized` always means there are some exceptions.

Comment: I like the idea that that the class' name in the constructor's declaration is the return type and not the name :-)

Comment: @AswinMurugesh I know, but my point is about how we are looking at constructors. I think, the second way, gives us a more understandable and touchable perspective. Isn't it?

Comment: I think that return type has nothing to do with OOP itself. Some Object Oriented languages don't require return type for methods. What you describes concerns more C family languages such as C# and Java.

Comment: @C.Champagne well in C# and Java as far as I know, methods must have a return type, even `void`. And in C# I'm pretty sure `void` is a `struct`: `public struct Void { }`

Comment: @Javad_Amiry in Python you don't have to specify a return type.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, and it’s provoked by the confusing syntax in C++, Java, etc. Your point of view is similar to what Python does with `__init__` – see http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html Fundamentally constructors are *class* methods, not *instance* methods, because there is no existing instance; that’s why they’re different. Typically what you define is actually just the *initializer* (fills in values), not the *allocator* (allocates memory); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_lifetime for details.

Comment: If constructors had a return type, they would need a `return` statement inside them. Which they do not.

Comment: The fact that Java and C# (and C++) require return types on methods is just a syntax rule that they all share. There is no principle of OOP that says so. The principles of OOP are encapsulation, polymorphism, classes and objects, etc. Nothing about programming language syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Operator `new` does two things:

1. Allocates memory for a new object (and the pointer to that piece of memory is assigned to obj in your example).
2. Calls the constructor which initializes the object with default values.

So, in that sense, constructor doesn't return anything. It's the `new` operator that returns the object. Constructors works as a decorator: it receives a piece of memory and initializes various bytes in that memory with default values.

It also answers your first point, that the constructor must have a return type. As the constructor only initializes some data allocated by the `new` operator it can't return anything, because if it did want to return something then the expression `new MyClass()` would, in fact, have to return two types at the same time!! One type would be the object allocated by operator `new` and the second type would be the same object decorated by the constructor.

If you want to be so picky about definitions I would rather suggest changing the name `method` in the description to something else (maybe decorator, like in the design pattern?).

And who said that a method must return a type? What about abstract methods, do they return anything?

**EDIT** to answer some of the questions:

Yeah, abstract methods have a return type but they don't actually return anything, only methods which implements the interface they define. My point was to show that not everything that is defined as *method* has to return a type. Some methods (or some language constructs) do return something and some don't, regardless of how you call them.

I guess in case of constructor it was easier to define them in terms of methods that don't return anything, because they are very similar to any other regular method, apart from the very fact that they don't actually return anything, rather than trying to make up another definition for a method-like construct that don't return anything.

Operator `new` doesn't say *create an object*. It's just an operator, a language construct. When the code gets compiled `new` actually ceases to exist, it's replaced with some assembler code to allocate and initialize a piece of memory that will represent the object.

Let's disassemble the steps taken when executing `new MyClass()` one by one:

1. Operator `new` allocates a piece of memory with the size needed to store all variables and metadata of class `MyClass` with all its parent and child classes.
2. The operator now executes constructors of all the parent classes of class `MyClass` (if any).
3. The operator executes constructors of all the child classes of class `MyClass` (member variables stored in `MyClass` which are not build-in classes themselves).
4. The operator finally executes the constructor of the class `MyClass`.
5. The operator `new` returns the created object (or a pointer to the allocated piece of memory).

Very rarely there is just one constructor to execute. If the class has parent classes and holds any custom classes within then the `new` operator has to execute a few, if not dozens of constructors before being able to return the object. Where would all the return types go if each constructor had to return something, and what would be the point of doing that if we can't do anything with whatever the constructors were to return?

**What animal is an operator?**

I think what is confusing here is the definition of an operator. Operator is not a method to invoke. Thinking that `new` says to create an object is as wrong as saying that `+` says to add two objects or that `=` says to compare objects. Operators can be overloaded but the principle is that operators are language constructs that define operations the language (the compiled assemble code) performs, e.g. assign to a variable a sum of two objects, create an object, etc. See [operators on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28programming%29).

Comment: Well abstract method have return type in Java, C# and other languages. public abstract double getPerimeter(); is totally valid

Comment: My English is too bad, I wish I can explain my point. `new` says *create an object*, with what? with the accessible anonymous method located in this type: `MyClass`. And about abstract methods: do they do anything? Are they really methods or just signatures? Contracts that inherited classes must implement them? Also, the HAVE return type: `public abstract string MyMethod();` and when they get implemented (in inherited objects) and become real methods, they have return value. Aren't they?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry In Java, at least, a class A extending a parent B having an abstract method must implement this method unless A is abstract itself too. 

An abstract method is just a clause in a contract. It doesn't do anything by itself. It mentions WHAT to do and the concrete implementation specifies HOW.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include responses to some of the comments. I hope they will help you to better understand the difference between operators and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Who cares what descriptions of constructors are used in books? Why bother with the semantics?

The single purpose of constructors is to construct and instatiate an object, and there's no OOP without an object.
Constructors do something and don't retrun a value so that's why they are labeled by many books as "specialized methods" and the word specialized is used precisely because they don't need the void keyword in their signature.

It's quite clear what constructors do and how they do it so your question boils down to whether the constructors are properly described in literature or not, and while I happen to think they are, precisely because the word "specialized" is used, what's the point of wasting the time with that level of dissection?

If you go directly to the source (MSDN) you'll find this on constructors in C# Programming Guide:

> Whenever a class or struct is created, its constructor is called. A
>   class or struct may have multiple constructors that take different
>   arguments. Constructors enable the programmer to set default values,
>   limit instantiation, and write code that is flexible and easy to read.

As you can see MSDN is not labeling constructors as "specialized methods" (or anything else), it is just clearly and succintly describing what a constructor is and what is its purpose. That's just a part of how they designed their framework so what metaphores are used by some authors to describe constructors is completely irrelevant...

Finally, to quote the "Framework Design Guidelines":

> There is no such thing as the perfect design. Design is all about
>   making trade-offs, and to make the right decisions, you need to
>   understand the options, their benefits, and their drawbacks. If you
>   find yourself thinking you have a design without trade-offs, you are
>   probably missing something big instead of finding the silver bullet.

Making constructors the way they are could easily be viewed as just such a trade-off as described in that quote.